# Anypoint Studio 7.1 start-up error

Tags: mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I am trying to experiment with Mule Runtime 4 & Anypoint Studio 7.1.
I got the downloadable from -

https://mule-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/7.1.1-GA/AnypointStudio-for-win-64bit-7.1.1-201803182216.zip

while starting up AnypointStudio.exe, I keep getting the error message -

A JDK must be installed in order to run Anypoint Studio. Please install a JDK  and try again.

But I do the required version of JDK installed in my machine, as per https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/7.1/faq-jdk-requirement

Here's the output from java -version

java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Can someone help identifying the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solid answer is, Anypoint Studio 7+ only supports OpenJDK. I have both Oracle and OpenJDK installed on my machine. I had to bring OpenJDK and JRE setting up the order in Environment variables above Oracle JDK Path.

IF you have only OpenJDK, no changes to environment variables is required.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure Java8 was installed in your system and Update AnypointStudio.ini file with below lines.

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\javaw.exe
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it for me.  The Mulesoft web site stated that we had to replace Program Files with "progra~1", but this wasn't working.

Comment: For 7.3 version AnypointStudio.ini has  -vmarg as default and it has to to be removed and replaced with jdk javaw.exe.  Putting up jdk path at top of env variable is also recommended from my exp.

Answer (score 1):

@larsen

I think you have more than one version of java installed in your laptop, Please use the JDK 1.8 with the latest update  and remove or uninstall all the older versions of it.

Please don't forgot to configure the JAVA HOME and Path environment variables in your laptop user account. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhqE.png)

and if still the problem exists, then uninstall all the  versions of java and clear the temp folder of your laptop (or restart your laptop) and then try the fresh installation of jdk and jre 1.8 version, this kind of error comes when the jdk is not installed properly in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Above solution works but there is another solution which is to add JAVA_HOME and PATH variables into Window's System variables. Make sure to put %JAVA_HOME%/bin as first variable of PATH variables' value.

By doing that you don't need to change any default configuration . 
Studio7 try to find out JDK path from first variable of "PATH" values under system variable instead of user variable under Environment variables .

Answer (score 0):

not true, you can use as many JVM as you wish,
just make system path to javaw.exe and server\jvm.dll

..;D:\jdk1.8\jre\bin;D:\jdk1.8\jre\bin\server;D:\jdk1.8\bin;...

and JAVA_HOME D:\jdk1.8 and fix anypointstudio.ini accordingly above described to your path of javaw.exe in my case D:\jdk1.8\jre\bin\javaw.exe

Answer (score 0):

once you reinstall AnyPointStudio its not working plz follow the steps below..

step:1 Download AnyPointStudio (it should be extract in c:drive only )

step:2 download JDK8 Version(it will support JDK8)

after these two steps it will work successfully