# Anypoint Studio issue

Tags: installation, mule, anypoint-studio

I have downloaded AnypointStudio-for-win-64bit-7.3.0
[image]

But when i try to run getting below error
[image]

JDK installed properly and AnypointStudio-for-win-64bit-6.2.2 is also working fine. They why issue with newer version ?
[image]

Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add java details to AnypointStudio.ini file like

```
-vm
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe
```

Please refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49623636/anypoint-studio-7-1-start-up-error) for more details.

If you still get same error please check if have only one version of Java installed in your system.

Hope this helps.